# jquery file upload and resize image not working on server

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using the following jQuery file upload plugin to upload image files and resize it it is working fine in localhost.

While trying it in server i am receiving error:

```
["pamela.jpg"]{"jquery-upload-file-error":"Image file could not be found!"}
```

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$output_dir = "../images/img_user/";
if(isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]))
{
$ret = array();
$error =$_FILES["file"]["error"];
if(!is_array($_FILES["file"]["name"])) //single file
{
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
//img resize
require 'imgclass.php';
$resize_image = new Zebra_Image();
$resize_image->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
$resize_image->source_path = $output_dir.$fileName;
$ext = trim("$fileName");
$resize_image->target_path = '../images/img_user/'.$ext;
if (!$resize_image->resize(128, 128, ZEBRA_IMAGE_NOT_BOXED, 1))
{
// if there was an error, let's see what the error is about
switch ($resize_image->error) {
case 1:
$custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="Image file could not be found!";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
case 2:
$custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="Image file is not readable!";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
case 3:
$custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="Could not write target file!";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
case 4:
$custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="Unsupported image file format!";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
case 5:
$custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="Unsupported target file format!";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
case 6:
$custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="GD library version does not support target file format!";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
case 7:
$custom_error= array();
$custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="GD library is not installed!";
echo json_encode($custom_error);
die();
}//end switch
}//end resize error
//end resize
$ret[]= $fileName;
}
echo json_encode($ret);
}
?>
```

Seems like it is trying to resize the image before the whole file gets uploaded from local desktop to server. How can we ensure that resizing is done only after the whole file gets uploaded?? Seems like that is the issue as it is working fine in localhost. Help requested from experts.

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName); is this functions returned a true ?

Comment: do you have read and write permissions on your web server?

Comment: @long It is 755 for folder and images.

Comment: error gone after  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$output_di‌​r.$‌​fileName)) == true 
But image not getting uploaded. Seems like a permission issue.

Comment: Who is the file owner?Which group does the owner belong to?

Comment: @long It is the server user not www-data.

Comment: Thank you after chown it to www-data it is working fine

Comment: did chmod($image_path , 0640); to make it more secure

Comment: Using `$custom_error= array();` is soo [2000'ish](http://code.divshot.com/geo-bootstrap/). Completely obsolete, besides that a declaration before the `switch` would be more then enough.

Comment: Also, the security risks with `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);` is also from around the year 2000. 17 years out of date of security measures. Yes, you allow us to upload php files to your webserver without any effort.

Comment: @Xorifelse I am a newbie programmer. In your opinion what can be done to prevent it. I have prevented executables in the folder using htaccess.

Comment: Strip the file name of illegal characters, find info on that online. When stripped off, determine the file extension to see if you want it uploaded. Then use a interalnal php function to extract the file's mime and verify if that file extension matches that mine type. When all that is done, you can safely move the uploaded file to your directory.